# Show content on first load of ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I'm not sure how else to word the title, but the viewpager in my application works as it should - instantiating the current view along with left and right views.

What I would like to know is if I can display content of a non-viewpager element (in this case a listview) on just the first load of the viewpager and then update accordingly as the viewapager scrolls.

Relevant code:

```
_calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, m);
_calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, y);
holdTodaysDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, m);
holdTodaysDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, y);

_calendar = holdTodaysDate;

_calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, offset-1); 
month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
Log.d("Calendar", "Month Year" + month + " " + year);

eventsSummary.onEventsNavigation(month, year, date_value);

--calendar adapter--
```

The problem is `eventsSummary` (non-viewpager element) has to load using the initial month value when the viewpager loads, but since the viewpager loads thrice, month+1 is displayed in `eventsSummary`.

For example, February is the current month and it does display February the first time the viewpager loads as I can see in the log, but the viewpager instantiates the next and previous views too - so January is loaded and March. The `eventsSummary` finally displays the events for March while the main calendar (which is the ViewPager element) displays February.

How can I get `eventsSummary` to display the events for February, rather than March and then update its view with the month the user has swiped to?

I'm passing information between the fragments `eventsSummary` and the Calendar ViewPager container using the approach [shown here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I correct in understanding that you are setting the date in each fragment's `onCreate()`?

Perhaps you should instead observe what page the ViewPager is displaying, and trigger events [through an OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener%28android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener%29).